# textfile with scala

Tags: scala

I am currently learning scala and I want to perform the following task:
I have the following text file as input:

```
10 location String
10 age      String
10 Salary   String 
15 job      String
10 Name     String
15 Status   String
```

The code I should write can be described as follows: 
If a line starts with 15, the second field has to be replaced with the second field of the first previous line starting by 10. 
Hence the output shall look like:

```
10 location String
10 age      String
10 Salary   String 
15 Salray   String
10 Name     String
15 Name     String
```

Comment: Your sample date would imho better fit a description like 'If a line starts with 15, the second field has to be replaced with the second field of the LAST previous line starting by 10.' And what did you try? Where is your problem?

Comment: And what happens if there was no previous line starting with 10?

Comment: @ smac89: Good question , in this case an exception shall be handled. But we are dealing with copycobol files , it seems that first indexes are always 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace1510 (lines: List[String], last10: String) : List [String] =
  if (lines.isEmpty) Nil else {
  val row = lines.head.split ("[ \t]+")
  row(0).toInt match {
    case 10 => lines.head :: replace1510 (lines.tail, row(1))
    case 15 => (row(0) + " " + last10 + "\t" + row (2)) :: replace1510 (lines.tail, last10)
    case _ => lines.head :: replace1510 (lines.tail, last10)
  }
}

scala> replace1510 (lines.toList, "").mkString ("\n")
res180: String =
10 location String
10 age      String
10 Salary   String
15 Salary   String
10 Name     String
15 Name String
```

Depending on your needs, your output might need some cosmetics in the end.

I split the rows at blanks and tabs and expect the first value to be parseable as Int, matching over it.

Either (10) update the last10 value, or replacing the middle field with the memorized last10 value, or just handing the row through.

- So the input in the beginning is the whole list of 6 lines.
- *lines* is not empty.
- *lines.head*, which is "10 location String" is split into *row=(10)(location)(String)*.
- Then *row(0)*, which is "10", is converted to Int and matched for; it matches *case 10*.
- This returns *lines.head*, which is the entire line, combined with the result of the recursive call to *replace1510 (lines.tail, row(1))*, where `lines.tail` is the rest of the list, except the first line, and `row(1)` is "location".
- The rest is again splitted/matched, similarly leading to the 2nd line, now rest starting at line 3 with *age*.

My data preparation:

```
scala> val data = """10 location String
     | 10 age      String
     | 10 Salary   String 
     | 15 job      String
     | 10 Name     String
     | 15 Status   String"""
data: String =
10 location String
10 age      String
10 Salary   String
15 job      String
10 Name     String
15 Status   String

scala> val lines = data.split ("\n")
lines: Array[String] = Array(10 location String, 10 age      String, "10 Salary   String ", 15 job      String, 10 Name     String, 15 Status   String)
```

Comment: Hello , thanks a lot for your answer , as I mentioned above I am learning scala , so I have some question related to your code , how could you know that you are recursively processing the different lines ( here rows of the list) , when I read your code I understand that you are dealing with the first line ( head) but I can't see how you can go through other lines

Comment: A list can be split in head :: tail. The 3 alternative results are created as operations on head  and combining that with an operation on the tail like in the default case: `lines.head :: replace1510 (lines.tail, last10)`, where no operation is performed on the head, and the function is recursively called on the tail.

Comment: I already understood this , my question is how can you go the different lines , I don't see any for loop to parse the different lines of the textfile

Comment: thanks a lot, your detailed answer helped me to understand how it works

Comment: I am getting the following message of error: 66: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(String, String, String)]
 required: List[String]
 replace1510 (output2, "")
              ^
Currently my data in input looks like :

Comment: If you don't specify the data type of your data, we can only guess. Is it a file, a list of Strings or an Array of Strings (each line 1 String) or already splitted, each line a List or Seq or Array of Strings - or is the first field already an Int or some other numeric type? Scala can infer the typename often, but for us, to write fitting code, we need to know what it is, if we don't have the whole context. Extend the question with more details. Is it a file? How did you read it?

Comment: Adjusting the method to a different data format is possible. If lines are passed as "List[(String, String, String)]" (tuple3 of String) you needn't split it, since it is already split. But row(0) is is now lines.head._1, row(1) is lines.head._2 and so on. More convenient might be an intermediate variable `val triple = lines.head; triple._1.toInt match ...` or 'val (num, name, type) = lines.head; num.toInt match ...'. If you don't provide a [mcve], you have to expect that readers extend the missing parts of your question with what might be - with speculations.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using recursive method as suggested by others, another way to process your text is to use `foldLeft` to traverse the list of split substrings to carry out your processing logic.

Note that a `tuple` of (List[Array[String]], String) is used as the accumulator for `foldLeft` to iteratively transform the list of array as well as to carry over the string element for conditional replacement.

```
val textArr = scala.io.Source.
  fromFile("/path/to/textfile").
  getLines.map(_.split("\\s+")).
  toList

val id1 = "10"
val id2 = "15"

val outputList = textArr.foldLeft( (List[Array[String]](), textArr.head(1)) ){
  (acc, x) => x(0) match {
    case `id1` => ( x :: acc._1, x(1) )
    case `id2` => ( x.updated(1, acc._2) :: acc._1, acc._2 )
    case _ => ( x :: acc._1, acc._2 )
  }
}._1.reverse.
map(_.mkString(" "))
// outputList: List[String] = List(10 location String, 10 age String, ...)

outputList.foreach(println)
// 10 location String
// 10 age String
// 10 Salary String
// 15 Salary String
// 10 Name String
// 15 Name String
```

In case you aren't familiar with method `foldLeft`, it has the following signature.  More details can be found at this [Scala API doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B)

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

[UPDATE]

If your input data is a list of strings, you can create `textArr` as below and apply the above `foldLeft` transformation:

```
val stringList = Seq(
  "10 location String",
  "10 age      String",
  "10 Salary   String", 
  "15 job      String",
  "10 Name     String",
  "15 Status   String"
)

val textArr = stringList.map(_.split("\\s+"))
```

Comment: I am getting the following message 
 scala:71: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Array[String]]
 required: List[String]
 replace1510 (output2, "")

              ^
Currently my data in input looks like :                                                 10 FCRI1-COD_SI_DEST PIC X(04) 
15 FILLER PIC X(74) 
10 FCRI1-FIN_ENREG PIC X(02), Any idea how to transform the  List[Array[String]] to List[String]

Comment: @HAIFA, not sure I understand the said problem, as my solution does not have `replace1510()`.  In any case, I've expanded my answer to include another possible type of input data.